# dual booting xubuntu 22.04 and ubuntu 22.04, ubuntu showing up as windows

Tags: linux, grub2, dual-boot, xubuntu

I have two hard drives on my laptop - 1 TB HDD and 128 GB SSD - originally I had ubuntu 22.04 on the HDD and Windows 10 on the SSD and dual booted them - when I started my computer I had a choice in grub as to which would boot - I decided to put xubuntu on the SSD and now when I boot my only option is the Xubuntu partition and a Windows Boot Manager - but my system no longer has windows. The partitions look like the following:

```
sda                      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk  
├─sda1                   8:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda2                   8:2    0   1.7G  0 part  
└─sda3                   8:3    0 929.3G  0 part  
sdb                      8:16   0 119.2G  0 disk  
├─sdb1                   8:17   0   512M  0 part  
├─sdb2                   8:18   0   1.7G  0 part  /boot
└─sdb3                   8:19   0 117.1G  0 part  
  └─sdb3_crypt         253:0    0 117.1G  0 crypt 
    ├─vgxubuntu-root   253:1    0 115.1G  0 lvm   /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
    │                                             /
    └─vgxubuntu-swap_1 253:2    0   1.9G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
```

Essentially, both use LVM with cryptsetup. When I ran "sudo update-grub", it detected a Windows partition on sda, which has regular ubuntu 22.04:

```
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
```

How would I go about setting it up so I can switch between Xubuntu and Ubuntu on boot up? I noticed that sda has "boot/efi" but sdb has /boot, tho the size of the first two partitions are the same - is this the problem? Can I fix it w/o reinstalling?

Comment: Default install of Ubuntu is to use ESP on first drive. So installs to second drive do not have ESP. Users who want second drive or external drive to have ESP have this bug. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 the ESP & UEFI entries in UEFI are not erased, so you have to manually remove /EFI/Microsoft folder & with efibootmgr remove UEFI boot entry. All Ubuntu and many unofficial versions use same ubuntu UEFI entry. Is sdb1 FAT32 and just needs esp,boot flags? And install of grub to it, see work arounds in bug report. Use efibootmgr to create entry that says xubuntu